# List comprehensions with multiple conditions

Tags: python, list-comprehension, multiple-conditions

I know this subject has been touched on a few times already, but all the topics I inspected did not ask the question I am about to ask (I think). What is wrong with declaration below?

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits as letters, digits

combinations = [letter1 + letter2 + digit1 + digit2 for digit1 in digits if (digit1 % 2 == 0) for digit2 in digits if (digit2 % 2 == 0) for letter1 in letters if (letter1 != 'a') for letter2 in letters if (letter2 != 'A')]

print combinations[:500]
```

I keep on getting:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Would be great to know what I am doing wrong, since I could swear I am following proper syntax here...

Comment: Your comphrehension is not readable, why not use a regular for loop

Comment: Your `import` assigns `'0123456789'` to both `letters` and `digits`

Comment: Use `range()` to get the digits you want and `itertools.product` to combine them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems.

First of all, your import doesn't do what you think it does:

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters, digits as letters, digits
>>> letters
'0123456789'
>>> digits
'0123456789'
```

Try something like this instead?

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters as letters, digits as digits
>>> letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> digits
'0123456789'
```

Secondly, when you use the `%` operator on a number, it's mod, but when you use it on a string, it's the `format` operator. You're using it on a string, hence the mumble about string formatting. If you want it to be the mod operator, you have to int() the thing you're using it on.

```
int(digit1) % 2
```

Thirdly, I agree with the others who say this is not easy to read/understand. Writing it differently, using a loop or range or functional notation, or at least formatting it differently to make the structure more apparent, would be an improvement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for our reply. I touched the code up according to your feedback and now it works! :)

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!

(You can "accept" my answer if you are satisfied with it.)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do integer mod on a string containing a digit. I guess wrap `digitFOO % 2 == 0` like `int(digitFOO) % 2 == 0`.

As Chris_Rands points out, it still won't work properly because the imports are broken.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `digits` you import is a string, and so each `digit1` and `digit2` is also a (single-character) string. This makes (for example) `digit1 % 2` appear to be an attempt to use Python's string interpolation mechanism - it's a `%` operator with a string left-hand operand.

Because that operand contains no `%` signs, there is no marker to locate the insertion of the right-hand operand, `2`, hence the rather incomprehensible error message.

You should also lay your code out rather better - long single lines don't work!